# jQuery - Make dynamically created DIV remove itself on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

been struggling with this for a while now. Really hope someone can help me out.

Im trying to make divs which are removable when you click onto them.
They have a css-class 'tag-show' which is added and removed (this works), so the selector seems to be fine i guess..?

Why is the $(this).remove() not working?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// selectors
var module = $(".divCreate");
var list = module.find(".listTag");
var button = module.find(".divButton");

// the actual issue
button.click(function() {
        list.append("<div class='tag'>Tag</div>");
        setTimeout(function() {
            list.find(".tag").last().addClass("tag-show").on("click", function() {
                $(this).removeClass("tag-show");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                },190);
            });
        },40);

})
```

});

Comment: so first you click '.divButton', which adds classes and then when you click the '.tag' it deletes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"this" loses it's context in your setTimeout.
add a var containing this and use that instead.
like so

```
var self = $(this);
setTimeout(function() {
   $(self).remove();
},190);
```

I think that would fix it.

Comment: There's no need for $(self) since self is already a jQuery object.

Comment: it's also quite useful to mark the JQuery variable `$self` - that way you can tell at a glance what is what

Answer (score 1):

You should use the jQuery `.on()` function instead of `.click()`, as it works for dynamically created elements. Then you also don't have to apply it to the element each time it is dynamically added.

Somewhere else in your code within `$(document).ready(function() {});` add this event handler:

```
$('.listTag').on('click', 'div.tag', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

and it should work for any element that is matched by the `div.tag` selector.

Comment: This won't work on newly created `div.tag` elements. This should be: `$('.listTag').on('click', 'div.tag' ...`

Comment: Ahh, yes, I will make that change to the on code, but don't you agree that using the .on() function is better practice than DRGA's answer?

Comment: I definitely agree. We can't just expect everyone to know that concept already. That's why I'd rather go along with what the author has.

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the `setTimeout` callback is not referring to the `div` anymore. You could bind the callback to the `div` or do something like this:

```
var $this = $(this);
setTimeout(function() {
    $this.remove();
},190);
```

Comment: is it a bad practice? `$` prefix implies that it's a jQuery object of `this` (the `div.tag` element)

Comment: Yeah i know - using $ to refer to jquery objects is good practice - but someone who dont know that would eventually think that it's wrong or so :D - just a few thoughts

Comment: Ok :D Perhaps I should have just suggested `bind` / `call` / `apply`

Answer (score 0):

I have made some improvments to your code, adding comments where it was needed. Just check the code below and its comments.

Your problem with remove is that the `this` in your case is "triggering" the closest parent, which is `setTimeout`, not clicked element.

For a better understanding just try to call `console.log(this);` inside timeout function and click function, you will see the difference.

I have made an [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz1s5uob/) which can help you understand better (open developer tools to see the console result)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // when you keep DOM elements in variables is better to put $ in the beginning
    var $module = $(".divCreate");

    // faster than .find()
    var $list = $(".listTag", $module);

    // can not call 'on' with variable
    //var $button = $(".divButton", $module);

    // called through document since we need to handle dynamic added elements - check event delegation
    $(document).on("click", ".divButton", function() {
            $list.append("<div class='tag'>Tag</div>");

            setTimeout(function() {
                // some improvments
                $(".tag", $list).last().addClass("tag-show");
            }, 40);

            // Just keep this if you have divButton attached to an anchor element
            // Useful for preventing default behvaiour - in this case adding "#" to url
            return false;
    });

    // Do not need to create the event inside that event
    $(document).on("click", ".tag-show", function() {
        // Since we use an element more than once is better to
        // add it into a variable to avoid performance issues - js caches it and call the variable
        var $el = $(this); // our needed 'this'
        $el.removeClass("tag-show");

        setTimeout(function() {
            // 'this' here returns some properties of window (where setTimeout belongs), we need to call element cached above 
            //(the 'this' above contains what we need) 
            $el.remove();
        }, 190);
    }); 
});
```

Note : still do not understand why you need these timeouts but it s up to you, maybe you need them with a bigger interval :D

Comment: thanks for the advices, ill implement some of that stuff into my code! since my question was specific for the $(this) issue tho, i selected a previous answer as the right one, so people can find what they are looking for more quickly.

Comment: oh, and the timeouts are there to wait for the css transition to finish, and to wait for the dom element to be created (40ms) before i add a class to it (so the animation shows). Ive changed that to: $(this).on('transitionend' ...) now tho, which also fixed my initial problem. Havent found a solution for the 40ms delay yet tho.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps this is a better way to accomplish the same task?

```
// selectors
var module = $(".divCreate");
var list = module.find(".listTag");
var button = module.find(".divButton");

// the actual issue
button.click(function() {
    list.append("<div class='tag'>Tag</div>");
})

$(document).on('click','.tag', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7daffjh8/

Comment: are you kidding? this is a trillions times easier to read and sets the click events globally rather than after another click event and after a setTimeout delay

Comment: This is better than the original codes. The only issue is that scope is not that restricted (we don't know if there are other `.tag` elements outside of `list`). But I do believe that this does not deserve a down vote @Toni

Comment: @Orland explaining why is better than just stating that it's better

Comment: You're right. I think it's better since you would just need to bind to a single element (ancestor) instead of binding to every instance of `div.tag`